# Project Euler #8 Answer is to large to get valid answer

Tags: c++, iteration, largenumber

I have looked through the results on here to try to see where my error is. I am not looking for an answer to the solution but rather a hint as to what I overlooked to result in the wrong answer. That being said let's get into it.

I am working on Project Euler questions and I am currently on number 8. This question I believe is supposed to test you on your knowledge of iterating and storing large numbers. I have tried to store the value as an unsigned int, long long int, and as a string but all of which gave me different wrong answers. As I mentioned before, I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction to were I have overlooked or maybe have not researched thoroughly enough.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
   vector<int> numberList = "I broke the number provided into individual one digit integers";
   string sum;
   string answer;

for(auto it = numberList.begin(); it != numberList.end(); it++)
    {
        auto it2 = next(it, 1);
        auto it3 = next(it2, 1);
        auto it4 = next(it3, 1);
        auto it5 = next(it4, 1);
        auto it6 = next(it5, 1);
        auto it7 = next(it6, 1);
        auto it8 = next(it7, 1);
        auto it9 = next(it8, 1);
        auto it10 = next(it9, 1);
        auto it11 = next(it10, 1);
        auto it12 = next(it11, 1);
        auto it13 = next(it12, 1);

        if(it12 == numberList.end())
        {
            break;
        }

        sum = to_string(*it * *it2 * *it3 * *it4 * *it5 * *it6 * *it7 * *it8 * *it9 * *it10 * *it11 * *it12 * *it13);

        if(sum.compare(answer) > 0)
        {
            answer = sum;
        }
    }
    cout << answer << endl;
}
```

My plan of attack for this solution was to have 13 iterators that are updated on each loop and I would use these values to multiple and find the solution. The problem that I found was that the resulting number is to large for an int resulting on overflow. I then tried long long and unsigned which both resulted in a wrong answer. This version of the solution I tried to store it in a string which also resulted in a wrong answer. It is important to note that I am trying to keep this solution in linear time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please describe the propensity l problem you are trying to solve, the input, expected output and actual output (a [mre]), your code as it is doesn't even compile

Comment: Side note: `to test you on your knowledge` Project Euler is just a collection of really good problems, they are not "structured" as to anyhow test or evaulate you. `could point me in the right direction` - You are still usig `int` for you computation. You could use `long long` at least...

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for the response. I attempted the long long int and it worked perfectly. I would argue though that Project Euler while not testing your knowledge seeing as you are not structured, does test your understanding of effiency and methods seeing they technically have a time limit on how long each solution should take to complete. Even if it is unnecessarily long.

Comment: If `it12 == numberList.end()` is true, then UB has been invoked in `auto it13 = next(it12, 1);`. The `if` statement is probably optimized out by decent compilers.

Comment: Notice that according to your string comparison, 2 is bigger than 10.

Comment: I used python for questions involving large numbers so I would not have to worry about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a standard architecture (where `long long` are 64 bits long), you should not need a `std::string` for this problem since you are multiplying 13 digits, so the result will always be less than `10^13`, which easily fits in a `long long` (`2^63 ~ 10^19`).

The issue with your code is that you are performing the multipliation using `int`, so you overflow before the conversion:

```
sum = to_string(*it * *it2 * *it3 * *it4 * *it5 * *it6 * *it7 * *it8 * *it9 * *it10 * *it11 * *it12 * *it13);
```

Here `*it`, `*it2`, ..., are iterators of `int`, so you get a  product in the `int` domain which overflow before the conversion `to_string`.

You should use a `std::vector<long long>` to store the digits or converts the first one to a `long long`:

```
sum = (long long) *it * *it2 * *it3 * *it4 * *it5 * *it6 * *it7 * *it8 * *it9 * *it10 * *it11 * *it12 * *it13;
```

And `sum` / `answer` can simply be `long long`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the help. I thought I was outsmarting the overflow by assigning to a string and didn't even think to change the vector.